# how to validate a textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check a textarea whether it is empty or not. For this I write the following code:

```
function validateForm(theForm) {
    var problem_desc = document.getElementById("problem_desc");

    if (problem_desc.value == '') {
        alert("Please Write Problem Description");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}​
```

For the first time it is working fine. But If I remove the text from the textarea the above function is returning true value i.e., it is assuming the previous text I've entered into the textbox. Can anybody kindly tell me where is the problem?

Comment: It seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/XHUZ4/

Comment: Maybe relevant to show your HTML

Answer (score 4):

I am getting it correctly. This is what I did.

1. Click on validate, it said `Please Write Problem Description`.
2. Write something and click. Nothing happened.
3. Remove the text. Click on validate, it said `Please Write Problem Description`.

Note: Use a `trim` function to eliminate empty spaces.

#### Code:

```
function validateForm(theForm) {
    var problem_desc = document.getElementById("problem_desc");

    if ($.trim(problem_desc.value) == '') {
        alert("Please Write Problem Description");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TZGPM/1/ *(Checks for Whitespaces too!)*

Comment: Yor are right @Praveen Kumar. I use the trim() method. But still it is not working. My trim() method is given below                                                                            function trim(s) 
{
 return s.replace( /^\s*/, "" ).replace( /\s*$/, "" );
}

Comment: @user1407310 Is it possible for you to use jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Do check for white space in the value like this

```
if (problem_desc.value.match (/\S/)) { ... }
```

or other way check for length

```
 problem_desc.value.length == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces and calculate length of the value attribute.

```js
function validateForm(theForm) {
    var problem_desc = document.getElementById("problem_desc");

    if (problem_desc.value.replace(/ /g,'').length) {
       return true;
    } else {
       alert("Please Write Problem Description");
       return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="problem_desc"></textarea>
<button onclick="validateForm()">Validate</button>
```